# Why do I get TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable using for loop and not with list-comprehension in python

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, typeerror

This returns a type error

```
difference = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(len(difference)-1):
    difference = difference[i+1] - difference[i]
```

But this works fine

```
difference = [difference[i+1]-difference[i] for i in range(len(difference)-1)]
```

What am I missing here? I thought they were the same.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `difference = ...`? You're _reassigning_ `difference` entirely, when you should assign to `difference[i]`.

Comment: We may need a canonical duplicate for these kinds of questions... I swear this gets asked about 3 times a week...

Comment: @Aran-Fey I had imagined this was going to be closed soon, hence the comment and not an answer. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reassigning the variable `difference` during the loop. After the first iteration, it no longer contains a list, it contains the result of `difference[1] - difference[0]`, which is an integer.

You should create a new list for the result.

```
newdiff = []
for i in range(len(difference)-1):
    newdiff.append(difference[i+1] - difference[i])
```

The second version works because you don't reassign the variable until the list comprehension is done, not each time through the loop.

Comment: exacly and list comprehension stores results as temporary values

Comment: @Take_Care_ Um, what do you mean?

Comment: @COLDSPEED just that `[difference[i+1]-difference[i]` is adhoc stored in list when list comprehension happends.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line in the loop:

```
    difference = difference[i+1] - difference[i]
```

Here, you set the variable `difference` to an integer. So, on the second loop, you try to index an integer. Eg, you try to say that `difference = 1[2] - 1[1]`, which makes no sense whatsoever. This is what the error *"Integer is not subscriptable"* means.

You need to make a *new* list, which is what the list comprehension does before changing your variable. That's why it doesn't give a type error.

I think your code should be:

```
for i in range(len(difference)-1):
    difference[i] = difference[i+1] - difference[i]
difference = difference[:-1] # drop last element.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here additional way to do this with python library itertools :

```
from itertools import accumulate 
difference = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
difference = list(accumulate(difference, lambda x,y : y-x))
```